# Has anyone worked on OpenCV2.1 (pyOpenCV) , Python and Maya2010?

Tags: opencv, python-2.6, maya, importerror

I am using

1. python 2.6.1
2. corresponding numpy (http://space.dl.sourceforge.net/project/numpy/NumPy/1.5.0/numpy-1.5.0-win32-superpack-python2.6.exe)
3. corresponding pyOpencv (http://pyopencv.googlecode.com/files/pyopencv-2.1.0.wr1.2.0.win32-py2.6.exe)
4. MAYA2010 (with python 2.6.1)

   > ```
   > import sys
   >
   > sys.version_info
   >
   > #Result: (2, 6, 1, 'final', 0)#
   > ```

I tried `from pyopencv import *` in python IDE it works perfect. I also tried reading and saving file. That also worked perfectly.

But appending path in Maya2010 (`sys.path.append('C:\Python26\Lib\site-packages')`) for installed python2.6 OR pasting pyopencv and numpy folder to Maya2010 (in required folder : from "C:\Python26\Lib\site-packages" to "D:\Program Files\Autodesk\Maya2010\Python\lib\site-packages") are giving following error messages :

```
# Error: ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified procedure could not be found. #
```

on doing :
`from pyopencv import *`

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You have to do `sys.path.append('C:\\Python26\\Lib\\site-packages')` with double black-slash (`\\`) on Windows to specify the path correctly.

```
import sys
sys.path.append('C:\\Python26\\Lib\\site-packages')
sys.path.append('D:\\Program Files\\Autodesk\\Maya2010\\Python\\lib\\site-packages')
```